# Some text missing from loaded page

Tags: puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to go to URL:https://www.booking.com/hotel/us/l-39-horizon-resort-amp-spa.en-gb.html

The following text in the hotel description sometimes shows up and sometimes not

Hotel Chain: The Leading Hotels of the World

Does anyone knows why this happens?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let bookingUrl = 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/us/l-39-horizon-resort-amp-spa.en-gb.html';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false ,slowMo: 250});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(bookingUrl, { waitUntil : 'networkidle2' });
    await delay(4000);
});
```

Comment: give us the code that you wrote. we cannot answer you what you do wrong without the code. Probably you have to wait until the page is fully loaded

Comment: try using {waitUntil : ['networkidle2', 'domcontentloaded']}

Comment: Hi Niral, Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried waiting for it?

```
const selector = '#hotel_main_content > div.hp_hotel_description_hightlights_wrapper > div.hotel_description_wrapper_exp.hp-description > div.hp_desc_main_content > p.summary.hotel_meta_style';
await page.waitFor(selector, { visible:true });
```

A consideration about my code: I copied the elector with the Chrome devtools but it could change with time, make a try and if it works, refine it.